# Cannot Open a NPY file in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pickle, spyder

I collected data for a machine learning project, and I saved the data as .npy files, and they have the format of

```
[[multidimarray][multidimarray][multidimarray][multidimarray]]
```

The .npy files vary in size. I'm using Python 3.7.6 64 bits. The problem I'm having is as follows:

```
array = pickle.load(fp, **pickle_kwargs)

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

I try to load the .npy files with `with np.load(os.path.join(path, file), allow_pickle=True) as data:` but it always gives me the EOFError. I don't think the file is corrupted, because I have a file around 800MB and I can load that one but not one that is around 2.5GB.

If it helps when I collected the data I would do `np.save(file_name, training_data)` multiple times in a loop and overwrite the existing file when the `len(training_data)%1000 ==0`.

Any thoughts on why I can't load it? Thanks!

Edit: Here's the loop I use to make the .npy files:

```
file_name = SAVING_PATH + str(int(time.time())) + '.npy'

if os.path.isfile(file_name):
    print('File exists, loading previous data!')
    training_data = list(np.load(file_name))
else:
    print('File does not exist, starting fresh!')
    training_data = []

while True:
    #screen is a npy array
    screen = getscreen()

    arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4 = getdata(screen)

    cv2.imshow('window',screen)

    training_data.append([arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4])

    if len(training_data) % 500 == 0:
        print(len(training_data))
        np.save(file_name, training_data)

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print(len(training_data))
        np.save(file_name, training_data)
        break
```

Comment: Have you tried just `with np.load(os.path.join(path, file))`? Can you post the loop code in which you save the file?

Comment: @Ehsan If I don't include the allow_pickle=True, python won't let me load the file due to a ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False. I've added the loop in the post

Comment: also I'm pretty sure I have enough memory to load the file in

Comment: Hi @wang_yi76! Have you figured out a solution to this problem?